# How can I be sure this local variable is set after switch statement?

Tags: php, switch-statement, phpstorm

I have a scenario in my code where PhpStorm alerts me that a local variable `$offers` may be undefined. You can find the code scenario below as well as the alert from the IDE. Is intellisense right or wrong? The local variable is set regardless of the case as far as I can see.

Code:

```php
function checkProduct($product, $retailerId){
    switch (isTokenValid(getBearerToken())){
        case true:
            $offers = getOffers($product, getBearerToken());
            break;
        case false:
            requestBearerToken();
            $offers = getOffers($product, getBearerToken());
            break;
    }
  if(!isBestOfferOurs($offers)){
    alertRetailer($product);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Replacing the false case to a default seems to resolve the issue and this ensures that `$offers` is always set.

```php
switch (isTokenValid(getBearerToken())){
    case true:
        $offers = getOffers($product, getBearerToken());
        break;
    default:
        requestBearerToken();
        $offers = getOffers($product, getBearerToken());
}
```

Alert:

[image: php alert]

Comment: You can add a `default` value to match one of those two cases, or set it to a null value before the switch.

Comment: Other option can be to check inside `if` condition that $offers is not null.

Comment: Would have thought rewriting the code to have a simpler `if` would produce much better code

Comment: @NigelRen this is true but for the sake of curiosity I'd like to know if this works as well. I reproduced the scenario using an if-statement. This results in another alert from PhpStorm about common parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either preset the variable at the beginning of your function to an empty value, or you could add a `default` case to your switch statement below the `false` case. Either of those should satisfy your IDE.

Even though PHP `switch` statements do a loose type comparison (https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), PhpStorm doesn't seem to know that and thinks that there could be a value that isn't satisfied by your `switch` statement (which is why I suggested adding a `default` case). So it's technically wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! My problem is though that I want to be sure that either way $offers is set with valid data instead of satisfying my IDE.

Comment: Because PHP switch statements are loose type comparisons, you are guaranteed valid data. null will evaluate to false - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose.

Comment: So in my scenario the IDE would be wrong? Didn't know that was possible xD

Comment: I just tested in PhpStorm, and even if you declare a return type of `bool` on the `isTokenValid()` function, it still throws the warning. Either of the options I suggested will remove the warning.